# Iterate through dict with keys being strings with index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following form:

```
dic = {
    "Pbat_ch[1]": 1.976662114355723e-81,
    "Pbat_ch[2]": -1.449552217194197e-81,
    "Pbat_dis[1]": 2.8808538131862966,
    "Pbat_dis[2]": 2.0268679389242448,
    "Ebat[1]": 10.0,
    "Ebat[2]": 6.799051318681892,
    "Pgrid[1]": 115.48659741294217,
    "Pgrid[2]": 115.4865974120957,
}
```

I need to get 4 lists of the following form:

```
list1 = [1.976662114355723e-81, -1.449552217194197e-81]
list2 = [2.8808538131862966, 2.0268679389242448]
list3 = [10.0, 6.799051318681892]
list4 = [115.48659741294217, 115.4865974120957]
```

I am trying to find a way to do it by including the key, for example to have an index form 1 to 2 and do string matching with `"Pbat_ch["+str(index)+"]"`. Any better idea of how to achieve that?

Comment: Your way is best-- create new arrays based on this data. A worse way is to use eval() or something.

Comment: Are the numbers always in order? can there be missing ones? do you have an upper bound? What if you had "Pbat_ch[5]" instead of "Pbat_ch[2]"? would you want empty values and 5 items in the list?

Comment: @mozway The numbers are always in order and there are not missing ones. There always will be all the indexes meaning always 2 items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your "indices" are always in order and consecutive, use a simple collection in a defaultdict after reworking the key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in dic.items():
    out[k.rsplit('[', 1)[0]].append(v)

out = dict(out)
```

output:

```
{'Pbat_ch': [1.976662114355723e-81, -1.449552217194197e-81],
 'Pbat_dis': [2.8808538131862966, 2.0268679389242448],
 'Ebat': [10.0, 6.799051318681892],
 'Pgrid': [115.48659741294217, 115.4865974120957]}
```

accessing a given sublist:

```
out['Pbat_ch']
# [1.976662114355723e-81, -1.449552217194197e-81]
```

Or as list of lists:

```
list(out.values())

[[1.976662114355723e-81, -1.449552217194197e-81],
 [2.8808538131862966, 2.0268679389242448],
 [10.0, 6.799051318681892],
 [115.48659741294217, 115.4865974120957]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on having variables `list1`, `list2`, and so on:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dict_ = {
    "Pbat_ch[1]": 1.976662114355723e-81,
    "Pbat_ch[2]": -1.449552217194197e-81,
    "Pbat_dis[1]": 2.8808538131862966,
    "Pbat_dis[2]": 2.0268679389242448,
    "Ebat[1]": 10.0,
    "Ebat[2]": 6.799051318681892,
    "Pgrid[1]": 115.48659741294217,
    "Pgrid[2]": 115.4865974120957,
}

lists = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in dict_.items():
    key = key[:key.find("[")]
    lists[key].append(value)

for i, value in enumerate(lists.values(), start=1):
    # exec is unsafe. Don't use with untrusted inputs.
    exec(f"list{i} = {value}")

# The lists are as expected
print(f"{list1=}")
print(f"{list2=}")
print(f"{list3=}")
print(f"{list4=}")
```

Output:

```
list1=[1.976662114355723e-81, -1.449552217194197e-81]
list2=[2.8808538131862966, 2.0268679389242448]
list3=[10.0, 6.799051318681892]
list4=[115.48659741294217, 115.4865974120957]
```